# Opencv linking libraries - Undefined Reference

Tags: c++, opencv, linker, undefined-reference

I tried to compile opencv codes on raspberry pi 3.However, it gives always "undefined reference ... " error, i think there is a problem with linking.

**Compile:**

```
g++ `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` Face_Detection.cpp
```

**pkg-config opencv --libs:**

```
-L/opt/lib/ -L/opt/Deneme/opencv/a/ -opencv_calib3d -opencv_core 
-opencv_features2d -opencv_flann -opencv_highgui -opencv_imgcodecs 
-opencv_imgproc -opencv_ml -opencv_objdetect -opencv_photo -opencv_shape 
-opencv_stitching -opencv_superres -opencv_videoio -opencv_video
-opencv_calib3d_pch_dephelp -opencv_contrib_pch_dephelp 
-opencv_core_pch_dephelp -opencv_features2d_pch_dephelp 
-opencv_flann_pch_dephelp -opencv_gpu_pch_dephelp  
-opencv_haartraining_engine -opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp
-opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp -opencv_legacy_pch_dephelp
-opencv_ml_pch_dephelp -opencv_objdetect_pch_dephelp 
-opencv_video_pch_dephelp
```

**pkg-config opencv --cflags:**

```
-I/opt/Deneme/Include/opencv -I/opt/Deneme/Include/
```

**opencv.pc file:**

```
includedir=/opt/Deneme/Include/opencv
dir2=/opt/Deneme/Include/
libdir=/opt/lib/
libdir2=/opt/Deneme/opencv/a/

Name: opencv
Description: The opencv library
Version: 3.x.x
Cflags: -I${includedir} -I${dir2}
Libs: -L${libdir} -opencv_calib3d -opencv_core -opencv_features2d -         opencv_flann    -opencv_highgui -opencv_imgcodecs -opencv_imgproc -opencv_ml -opencv_objdetect -opencv_photo -opencv_shape  -opencv_stitching  -opencv_superres  -opencv_videoio  -opencv_video  -L${libdir2} -opencv_calib3d_pch_dephelp -opencv_contrib_pch_dephelp -opencv_core_pch_dephelp -opencv_features2d_pch_dephelp -opencv_flann_pch_dephelp -opencv_gpu_pch_dephelp -opencv_haartraining_engine -opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp -opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp -opencv_legacy_pch_dephelp -opencv_ml_pch_dephelp -opencv_objdetect_pch_dephelp -opencv_video_pch_dephelp
```

**error:**

```
Face_Detection.cpp:(.text+0x94): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'

Face_Detection.cpp:(.text+0xd8): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'

Face_Detection.cpp:(.text+0xec): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'

Face_Detection.cpp:(.text+0x128): undefined reference to `cv::resize(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::Size_<int>, double, double, int)'

Face_Detection.cpp:(.text+0x1e8): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'

Face_Detection.cpp:(.text+0x218): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'

Face_Detection.cpp:(.text+0x250): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'

Face_Detection.cpp:(.text+0x26c): undefined reference to `cv::hconcat(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&)'

Face_Detection.cpp:(.text+0x298): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'

Face_Detection.cpp:(.text+0x2c8): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could figure out which lib has imread/resize/hconcat and add that manually when calling g++, just to check if the problem is in finding the lib or with pkg-config. Also are you sure `-         opencv_flann` is handled properly?

Comment: I did what you said , but still it gives same error.

Answer (score 0):

It was linker order error. Try to change

```
g++ `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` Face_Detection.cpp
```

to

```
g++ Face_Detection.cpp `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv`
```

Comment: did you build the opencv from source? did you run `sudo ldconfig -v`?

Comment: Yes, i run ldconfig -v. Output doesn't contain any of these lib, but i run export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lib/

Comment: I'm not sure, but try to make a costume `opencv.conf` config in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`. This file just contains your opencv lib paths, `/opt/lib/` and `/opt/Deneme/opencv/a/`. Run `ldconf` and try to restart the pi.

Comment: Or simply make a link of all libs in `/opt/lib` to `/usr/local/lib` and make some costume to `opencv.pc`